# Books on Littlewood-Paley Theory

Tags: fourier-analysis, book-recommendation, littlewood-paley-theory

What are some good references for a beginner to learn about Littlewood-Paley theory? Most books I found are all not too beginner-friendly and I find myself spending more time doing background reading of other books than learning the actual theory.

Comment: Maybe terence tao's notes are suitable for you to get an insight and foundation.